# Use React Native components in a Meteor React web application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, web, react-native

As we're building a Meteor React web application which will be presented inside a web view inside a react native application. As you can probably tell by reading that sentence, this doesn't make much sense, but due to time constraints and the fact that the react native application is made by another team, we have decided to present it in a web view for now, and eventually convert it to RN as well.

So to prevent having to write everything twice, is there a way to use React Native components in Meteor? (So use `<View>` for example instead of `<div>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go down this path, you can use [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) to build React Native components for the web.

Just want to warn that while building your web client with RN components will definitely help you transition, you will still pretty much have to scrap all your client side Meteor logic when you transition later. The best RN meteor client currently is [react-native-meteor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-meteor) and is more of a proof of concept than anything -- trying to emulate key features of Meteor with a wrapper using a DDP client, but definitely not there yet.

So in the end, you're going to put in some serious hours making the conversion later or scrapping Meteor altogether when you go full native. If you're a fan of Meteor, I would suggest trying [apollo](http://www.apollodata.com) made by the folks at Meteor and works out of the box with RN. You can still get all the best features of Meteor like reactive data, optimistic UI, subscriptions, etc. and the learning curve is pretty mild.

Comment: I've used Meteor with React Native before successfully, though there are issues with scalability. The ddp-client package works fine and Spencer Carli has documented the integration very well. Nothing to worry about in the short-term, IMO.